# How come my sql query DELETE FROM gets stuck on "Loading..." even when the table has 0 rows?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I am having trouble figuring out why this one SQL query is getting stuck on "Loading". Even with **0 rows** in the table, it will just not work and get stuck on the "Loading" message. I don't have a problem with other queries. What might be the problem?

[image]

[image]

Comment: see  wait stats for the query

Comment: Is the table locked for some reason? (other program using it?)

Comment: Maybe `DELETE FROM \`Item\` WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP()>endTime;`

Comment: How do I "see wait stats"? And I don't think it is locked because I was able to delete all 1200 rows I initially had in table with "DELETE FROM table".

Comment: However `Item` is not reserved word and it might not be the issue.

Comment: I tried and it still stalls on "Loading..." when switched to \`Item\`

Comment: It could be a bug in PHPmyAdmin (I think that's what you're using), which because there are no results there's nothing to trigger the code to hide the "Loading" popup. Or it could be that you have been logged out of the site. I would suggest you close all browsers and try again.

Comment: Yes it is phpmyadmin. I don't think it has anything to do with the results because even when I had results, it didn't work. Which was why I tried to see if just "DELETE FROM Item" would work, which it did immediately. I will close browser and try again though.

Comment: Please, show us your table item

Comment: I have put it now.

Comment: It's a buglet in phpMyAdmin. Has been there for the last couple of releases.

Comment: @Dave is there anything I can do to get around it?

Comment: Ignore it and click on some other tab. As far as I can tell it is simply a bit of JavaScript that is "stuck" and nothing is really going on. I've learned to ignore it but it might help to report it as an error/bug.

Comment: But if I click some other tab, the query won't finish (not like it will anyway)?

Comment: Which phpMyAdmin version are you using?

Comment: @Isaac Bennetch 4.4.15.4

Comment: I am updating it now. I will let you guys know if it works after the update.

Comment: The updated version seems to be working just fine. Thank you guys.

Comment: Now it is broken for other statement... DELETE FROM Item WHERE store='store name';

Comment: Seems to be working on Firefox. Perhaps it was just Safari that was causing the problems.